# Model is not getting updated - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a simple page where there are list of existing item (these can be modified) and option to add new items to the existing list.

There are 2 sections, `CodeLookup` and `Benchmark`. Design of both section is same ( as explained above).

There is a link which will restore all the changes back to the initial state of page. 
On JS , there are arrays, one for storing the list which is displayed and a backup array which stores initial state of list. There is an add function which adds newly input data to the list. Lastly there is a cancel method (linked to cancel link) which will restore the list to its initial state. This cancel method just put the original list in the list used to display data.

Now the codelookup value is restored on hit of cancel the first time. But if you modify again in the list and hot cancel, restoration doesnot happen. Also benchmark is not resored at all. I have put breakpoint on Chrome dev tool and found that the list contain the values from original list however its not reflecting on UI.

Any help in fixing this is appreciated.

Below is the code :

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript"
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.7/angular.min.js"></SCRIPT>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var referenceDataMaintainenceApp = angular.module('referenceDataMaintainenceApp',[] );
    referenceDataMaintainenceApp.controller('referenceDataMaintainenceCtrl', function     ($scope) {

    $scope.orig_lookup_codes_details;
    $scope.orig_calendar_details;
    $scope.orig_pams_fields;
    $scope.orig_brokers_details;

    $scope.lookup_codes_details = [{'lookupName':'ac_asset','codeName':'ABCD','codeDetail':'sdfsdfsdf','ruleDetail':'sdsdsdsdsd','active':false}];
    $scope.benchmarks_details = [{'benchmarkName':'Bench1','benchmarkDesc':'First Entry','active':false}];

    $scope.orig_lookup_codes_details = angular.copy($scope.lookup_codes_details);
    $scope.orig_brokers_details = angular.copy($scope.benchmarks_details);



    $scope.addLookupCode = function() {


        $scope.lookup_codes_details.push($scope.new_lookup_code);

        $scope.new_lookup_code = getLookupCodeObject();


    };
    $scope.addBenchMark = function() {

        $scope.benchmarks_details.push($scope.new_benchmark);
        $scope.new_benchmark = getBenchMarkObject();

    };

    $scope.cancelData = function() {

        $scope.brokers_details       = $scope.orig_brokers_details;
        $scope.lookup_codes_details  = $scope.orig_lookup_codes_details;

        console.log("sdsd");
        //$http.post('/data/save', $scope.benchmarks_details);
    };


});

function getLookupCodeObject () {

    lookup_code = {
            lookupName :  '', 
            codeName : '',
            codeDetail : '',
            ruleDetail : '',
            active : false
    };

    return lookup_code;
}
function getBenchMarkObject () {

    benchmark = {
            benchmarkName :  '', 
            benchmarkDesc : '',
            benchmarkId : '',
            benchmarkType : ''
    };

    return benchmark;
}
</script>
 </head>
<body ng-app="referenceDataMaintainenceApp" ng-controller="referenceDataMaintainenceCtrl" >

<div><A class="operationalnav"  ng-click="cancelData()" 
                href="javascript:;">Cancel</A> </div>

                <br />
                <br />

<TABLE id="tblGridLookupCodes" class="tableData" border="0"
    width="100%">
    <THEAD>
        <TR bgColor="#eaeaea">
            <TD class="tableTitle" noWrap>Code Name</TD>
            <TD class="tableTitle" noWrap>Description</TD>
            <TD class="tableTitle" noWrap align="center">Active</TD>
        </TR>
    </THEAD>
    <TBODY>
        <TR ng-repeat="lookup_code_detail in lookup_codes_details">
            <td nowrap="nowrap">{{lookup_code_detail.codeName}}</td>
            <td nowrap="nowrap">
                <input type="text" name="codeLookupBean[0].codeDescription" 
                    maxlength="100" size="80" ng-model="lookup_code_detail.codeDetail" />
            </td>
            <td nowrap="nowrap" align="center">
                <input type="checkbox" name="codeLookupBean[0].active"
                ng-model="lookup_code_detail.active" />
            </td>
        </TR>
    </TBODY>
</TABLE>

<HR width="100%">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <INPUT id="codeNameInput" name="codeNameInput"
            maxLength="32" ng-model="new_lookup_code.codeName" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <INPUT id="descInput" name="descInput" maxLength="100"
            size="80" ng-model="new_lookup_code.codeDetail">
        </td>
        <td>
            <INPUT id="activeInput" name="activeInput" CHECKED type="checkbox"
                 ng-model="new_lookup_code.active" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <INPUT id="btnAddRow" class="btnz" title="Add Row" 
                ng-click="addLookupCode($event)" name="btnAddRow" value=" Add "
                type="button" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table> 


<br /><br /><br />




 <TABLE id="tblGridBenchmarks" class="tableData" border="0" width="100%">
    <THEAD>
        <TR bgColor="#eaeaea">
            <TD class="tableTitle" noWrap>Benchmark Name</TD>
            <TD class="tableTitle" noWrap>Description</TD>
        </TR>
    </THEAD>
    <TBODY>
        <TR ng-repeat="benchmark_detail in benchmarks_details">
            <TD>{{benchmark_detail.benchmarkName}}</TD>
            <TD><INPUT name="benchmarkBean[0].benchmarkDesc"
                maxLength="255" size="120" ng-model="benchmark_detail.benchmarkDesc"></TD>
        </TR>
    </TBODY>
</TABLE> 


<HR width="100%">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Enter Benchmark Name:<BR> <INPUT
            id="benchmarkNameInput" name="benchmarkNameInput"
            ng-model="new_benchmark.benchmarkName" maxLength="100" size="30">
        </td>
        <td>Description:<BR> <INPUT name="benchmarkDescInput"
            ng-model="new_benchmark.benchmarkDesc" maxLength="255" size="80">
        </td>
        <td><INPUT id="btnAddRowComment" class="btnz" title="Add Row"
            ng-click="addBenchMark($event)" name="btnAddRowComment"
            value=" Add " type="button"></td>

    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: can we see some code?

Comment: It is very hard to help you based on this story. We could really use your code to be able to improve it.

Comment: Cory Silva, Oscar Bout : I am so sorry. I made a miniature version of the screen in which there is this problem. Due to some distraction I forgot to attach the code. I have added it now.

Comment: can you just add both your functions into a controller. currently both of them are out of angular scope, so angular will not watch them for changes. or use @Mior answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like $digest cycle was not run at all or correctly.

try to run `$scope.$apply()` and see if it works.
example:
http://jsfiddle.net/00d0ux1x/

For more information see 
http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-angulars-apply-digest/

However in your case problem is

- `javascript:;` change to `javascript:void(0);`
- use `angular.copy();` to copy original array if you don't want to modify it in later use.
- in cancel function you are setting `$scope.brokers_details` and in view using `$scope.benchmarks_details`. (also having `orig_brokers_details`)

See fixed solution
http://jsfiddle.net/00d0ux1x/3/

Comment: I have added the miniature version of the code. The problem can be tested in the code.

Comment: As i said. Add `$scope.$apply();` at the end of your cancel method [see example](http://jsfiddle.net/00d0ux1x/). this should fix problem. Read about $digest cycle. Anyway somewhere in your code you are not using angular properly :)

Comment: I can see now that in your case its because you have `href` in cancel incorrectly set to `javascript:;`. Change it to `javascript:void(0)` instead and try once again.
You don't need $scope.$apply() anymore as it will be triggered by ng-click.

Comment: Also use use angular.copy() to copy original data as after first cancel you will copy reference to orinial data and later by adding you will modify them.  http://jsfiddle.net/00d0ux1x/2/

Comment: You have pointed it out correctly that href and the wrong name of list was creating the trouble for me. I have a working page now. Thanks for sharing the article on digest cycle and apply. When I used $scope.apply() I was getting error ( I understand from the article that ng-click automaticlally will begin digest cycle ). Is it that withing scope of angular its forbidden to use apply()?

Comment: No it is not forbidden. It was working working for me, not sure what was causing that error.

Comment: you need to call it $scope.$apply() with $ at apply. Try that.